# Transformation of continuous, independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, transformation

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent and identically distributed continuous random variables, with probability density function
>
> $$p(x)=\begin{cases}
>       \exp(-x), & \text{if}\ x>0 \\
>       0, & \text{otherwise}.
>     \end{cases}$$
>
> Let
>
> $$Z=\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}+2X_2$$
>
> Derive the probably density function of $Z$. It is sufficient to give the required pdf in the form of an integral of a joint pdf.

I have found the pdfs of $Y_1=\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}$ and $Y_2=2X_2$,

$$g(y_1)=\begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if}\ 0<y_1<1 \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}$$

and

$$g(y_2)=\begin{cases}
      \frac12\exp\left(-\frac{y_2}{2}\right), & \text{if}\ y_2>0 \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}.
    \end{cases}$$

But now I cannot see how to find the transformation of $Z$ as $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ do not have a joint pdf and are not necessarily independent.

Answer (score 0):

It's OK. Z is the sum and then the density is the convolution.

Exist this theorem: if $X_i$ are independent and $f_i$ borel-measuring functions, then $f_i(X_i)$ are independent

Comment: I.e.: yes, are independent

Comment: But $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ both depends on $X_2$, so your argument fails here.

Comment: The transformations of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ both depend on $X_2$, but the pdfs don't.

Comment: You can use the change variables theorem